# How to load default scripts included with WordPress correctly?

Tags: plugins, jquery, theme-options

I want to know the correct way to load existing scripts in `wp-includes/js/jquery/`

Example I want to load `jQuery UI Tabs`

What I have done for now

```
function sample_exists_code() {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. CONSTANTS_JS .'/jquery.js"></script>'."\n"; 
   echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. CONSTANTS_JS .'/jquery-ui.js"></script>'."\n"; 
}    
add_action('admin_head', 'sample_exists_code');
```

and this code working fine to load the UI tabs.

But when I try use this code and it's not working

```
function sample_exists_code() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');   
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');            
}    
add_action('admin_head', 'sample_exists_code');
```

Let me know the correct way to call the existing scripts.

---

Update :

```
// load existings js and template css.
function sample_admin_js_head()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs', null, array('jquery-ui-core','jquery'), null, false);
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . CONSTANTS_STYLES . '/style.css" />' . "\n";
}

// load up the menu page
function sample_add_page()
{
    $optionpage = add_theme_page(__('Theme Options'), __('Theme Options'), 'edit_theme_options', 'sample', 'sample_do_template');
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$optionpage", 'sample_admin_js_head' );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'sample_add_page');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@haha:**

`'admin_init'` is definitely an\ workable way to load scripts but you might also want to take a look at this blog post and consider using the `"admin_print_scripts-{$page}"` hook instead which can allow you to only load on your page when you need it and not burden the other admin pages:

- [**How To: Load Javascript With Your WordPress Plugin**](http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-load-javascript-with-your-wordpress-plugin/)

Here's code from the blog post, albeit modified a bit:

```
$your_page = add_management_page('myplugin','myplugin',9,__FILE__,
               'yourplugin_admin_page');
add_action("admin_print_scripts-{$your_page}",'yourplugin_jquery_tabs_loader'); 
function yourplugin_jquery_tabs_loader() {
  // what your plugin needs in its <head>
}
```

Comment: @haha - Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Codex docs on [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) strongly recommend to only hook it to `init`. Examples also show using `admin_init` for admin area, but I am not entirely sure this is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Got it worked :)

```
function sample_exists_code() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs', null, array('jquery-ui-core', 'jquery'), null, false);     
}    
add_action('admin_init', 'sample_exists_code');
```